# In PHP, what is just a backtick (’)?

Tags: php

I found this guide here, showing how to [add a meta box in WordPress](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/).

In there I can see this code:

```
/* Save the meta box’s post metadata. */
function smashing_save_post_class_meta( $post_id, $post ) {

  /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
  if ( !isset( $_POST['smashing_post_class_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['smashing_post_class_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return $post_id;

  /* Get the post type object. */
  $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

  /* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
  if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

  /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
  $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['smashing-post-class'] ) ? sanitize_html_class( $_POST['smashing-post-class'] ) : ’ );

  /* Get the meta key. */
  $meta_key = 'smashing_post_class';

  /* Get the meta value of the custom field key. */
  $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );

  /* If a new meta value was added and there was no previous value, add it. */
  if ( $new_meta_value && ’ == $meta_value )
    add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value, true );

  /* If the new meta value does not match the old value, update it. */
  elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );

  /* If there is no new meta value but an old value exists, delete it. */
  elseif ( ’ == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
}
```

What I don't get is the line using the tick `’`?
Is that some kind of new notation or something smart?

It's setting `$new_meta_value` to have the value `’` - and then later on checks if the value is equal to it. I mean... Why not using `null` or `false` or something?

Usually I'd just frown and move on. But this code seems pretty carefully crafted.

Comment: `’` has no special meaning in PHP. Using it like this will trigger a "use of undefined constant" warning and will use the literal value `"’"` in PHP 7 and lower. In PHP 8, this undefined constant issue will be a fatal error ([example](https://3v4l.org/G5vdX)). However, `’` is a valid identifier for a constant, so there may be another part of the code that calls `define("’", null);` and then [this would work fine](https://3v4l.org/3mYTg). But I don't see that in the tutorial you linked, nor is it something that WordPress does (currently, anyway. Maybe they did when the tutorial was written).

Comment: Those ticks are *not* backticks! Backticks are what you used to put some of the text in monospace and with a grey background. BTW: That code violates accepted coding guidelines in multiple ways concerning the formatting alone, don't expect too much from it! Also, it's ten years old and PHP changed substantially since then.

Comment: Looking at the example, I suspect this is supposed to be `''` - i.e. an empty string - but got picked up by some markdown-like parser, and then nobody noticed because the PHP code runs (until PHP 8).